# How to Count Value According to date in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I have multiple fields store in my database table, and there are `followup` field in my database and there are multiple dates store in this field. Now i want count data according to current date. But i am unable to do it.

I am getting same data multiple times, but i want in this format (Suppose there are 5 date store according to today date and they should be count 5, so that i can get the today followup clients )

Please let me know how i can do it.

Here are my controller code..

```
public function index()
 {
$lead=Lead::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
return view('admin.lead.index',compact('lead'));
 }
```

and here are my view file..

```
<div class="panel-heading">
@php
$mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$checkdate=$mytime->toDateTimeString();
@endphp
<div class="panel-title">Today Follow Up's: 
    @foreach($lead as $lws)
        <span class="label label-warning">
            {{($lws->followup=$checkdate)}}
        </span>
    @endforeach
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to get only today's follow ups:

```
$lead=Lead::whereDate('followup', date('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

or to count the records:

```
$lead=Lead::whereDate('followup', date('Y-m-d'))->get()->count();
```

Comment: this works for me but i have one more issue, i want to get `status` value according to today date. there are `Site Visit` in `status` column. So i want to get the number of `Site Visit` by according to today date. Please let me know what i can do in same code as you mention above.

Comment: @sainitor it it better you asked this as a different question. So that both question must be separate

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
 {
$mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$checkdate=$mytime->toDateString();
$lead=Lead::whereDate('created_at', $checkdate)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
return view('admin.lead.index',compact('lead'));
 }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.